# NetBeans option to discard remote sync errors

Tags: netbeans, windows-8

I'm getting the following error:

```
Upload Files on Save failed (more information in IDE log).
Disable this functionality for project x for this session?
```

In the IDE Log it sais:

```
STOR file.x
150 Ok to send data.
```

So this looks like a Bug (NB 7.3 newest, 64bit Win8) because files get uploaded w/o error.
I activated passive mode and ignore disconnect errors in the manage connection window.
Using explicit TLS on a remote host.

**Is there any way to fully discard these fail messages?**

Update:

I think it's a bug in NetBeans. When I chose 'New File -> any File' it brings the message (upload works tho!), when I hit a specific file 'New File -> PHP Class File' the message does not appear..